# Why my cube edges is included on uv map?

Tags: uv

I have a cube that has a cube hole in the middle, front to back.
When I UV unwrapped it, why there are some edges that come with it?
I don't get it, why edges get uv unwrapped? Shouldn't it only the faces of the object?
[image]

Comment: there are small dots on the edges, are you sure you've not beveled by accident?

Comment: Hemm... I did accidently click bevel modifier, but I've delete it afterward,  I thought It wasn't applied. But hei thanks for the clue.

Comment: to fix that you can simply Alt M > Merge By Distance